# Getting mmm-mode to work in emacs 24

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs

I have been trying to get mmm-mode to work, specifically for Rails development. I have followed the install instructions and I can't get to the specific mixed mode and special highlighting I was looking for. Most specifically erb files. Here is my .emacs file:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (zenburn)))
 '(custom-safe-themes (quote ("71b172ea4aad108801421cc5251edb6c792f3adbaecfa1c52e94e3d99634dee7" default)))
 '(show-paren-mode t))
(custom-set-faces
 )

;; File associations.
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.builder$" . ruby-mode) auto-mode-alist))

(require 'mmm-auto)
(setq mmm-submode-decoration-level 0)
(mmm-add-group
 'fancy-html
 '((html-erb
    :submode ruby-mode
    :match-face (("<%#" . mmm-comment-submode-face)
                 ("<%=" . mmm-output-submode-face)
                 ("<%"  . mmm-code-submode-face))
    :front "<%[#=]?"
    :back "%>"
    :insert ((?% erb-code       nil @ "<%"  @ " " _ " " @ "%>" @)
             (?# erb-comment    nil @ "<%#" @ " " _ " " @ "%>" @)
             (?= erb-expression nil @ "<%=" @ " " _ " " @ "%>" @)))))

(add-to-list 'mmm-mode-ext-classes-alist '(html-mode nil fancy-html))
```

Despite having a smooth install process following the instructions I have yet to be able to get highlighting to work in my erb files. I am running emacs 24 if that matters. So I followed the directions on in the download. I placed the folder afterwards in my .emacs.d folder. I have access to mmm-mode stuff in M-x. I just don't get highlighting for my modes and I can't find any reference to the declared modes.

PS: Side note I can't get my zenburn theme to stick but that's a different mater.

EDIT: The "instructions" I am referring to are at [THIS](http://groups.google.com/group/emacs-on-rails/browse_thread/thread/7b5d82d94bf0106e/0397a909fae76ee9) link and the INSTALL file included with the targz in the download.

Comment: What installation instructions are you following?  When you say "highlignting" you mean just changing the background of the special regions?  Full font-locking within those regions doesn't work AFAIK.

Comment: Edited...hopefully that answers your question. Am I mistaken that I should find either a fancy-html or html-erb mode given that addition to my .emacs? I'm still a little new at emacs customization without ELPA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately Emacs has no good canonical multi-mode editing story.  sanityinc (Steve Purcell) has patched up MMM-mode for Emacs 24 here: https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode

His config is here: https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d

as `init-ruby-mode.el` and `init-mmm.el`

but it's far from ideal (no indentation support, only highlight special regions.)

Other have had luck with nxhtml.

EDIT: add pointer to sanityinc's config

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot this evening and see how it goes.

Comment: I tried to build this package like the standard package but it is missing a config file. I grabbed the one from the standard install and it didn't seem to work. Make blows up on it. How exactly does one build it? The instructions are from the standard build.

Comment: PS: I went through the generated make file to correct the paths...still a no go.

Comment: I assume you still mean MMM-mode?  I added pointers to sanityinc's config.  There is no build step required, just add the mmm-mode's dir to your `load-path` and byte-compile if you want.

Comment: Depending on when I get home I will give it a shot. Thanks. I'd have a conclusion already but I've been a little busy :P

Comment: Wow, thanks. That added quite a bit of stuff I was adding myself with minimal effort.

Answer (score 4):

An update on the situation:

1) The highlighting problems should be fixed now.

2) To get smart indentation, see `mmm-erb.el` in https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode and the instructions in its header.