# Have Emacs edit Python docstrings using rst-mode

Tags: python, emacs, restructuredtext

How to I get Emacs to use `rst-mode` inside of docstrings in Python files?  I vaguely remember that different modes within certain regions of a file is possible, but I don't remember how it's done.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Emacs package that supports that is `mmm-mode`.  Ensure that's installed, and then code like this as part of your Emacs startup should do it:

```
(require 'mmm-mode)
(setq mmm-global-mode 'maybe)
(mmm-add-classes
 '((python-rst
    :submode rst-mode
    :front "^ *[ru]?\"\"\"[^\"]*$"
    :back "^ *\"\"\""
    :include-front t
    :include-back t
    :end-not-begin t)))
(mmm-add-mode-ext-class 'python-mode nil 'python-rst)
```

I tested this with some Python programs and it seems to work properly.

Note that this will switch to rst-mode for every triple-quoted string, not just the ones at the start of a function definition.  You could probably restrict it to just the ones at the start of a function definition with a more complex front regex, but I'm not completely sure how to handle it since I think mmm-mode definitions by default match a line at a time.

**Edit**: My original version would put Emacs into rst-mode at the point of a single line docstring and then leave it in that mode up until the start of the next docstring.  This version avoids putting Emacs into rst-mode if there is another double quote on the same line as the start of the docstring, which still isn't perfect but should be closer.

Comment: You need to set `include-back` to `t`. Otherwise, `python-mode` thinks that the actual code is in docstrings.

Comment: This works, but sometimes the docstring delimiters seem to "leak" to `python-mode`, causing it to interpret code between docstrings as a docstring. For example, [this](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/solvers/ode.py#L2688-2759) whole block is rendered as a docstring.

Comment: How hard is it to setup the faces so that a different set of `rst-mode` faces are used in this context than in regular `rst-mode`?

Comment: Oh, good point about include-back.  I'll edit the answer for that. I'm currently using Emacs 23 on Debian testing with the code above (after the edit to fix the start pattern and with the `include-back` foix), and the ode.py example works correctly for me, including in the region that you indicate.  This is with mmm-mode 0.4.8-7.  Are either of those versions different for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, given how mmm-mode works, I don't think rst-mode is aware that it's running any differently, so I don't know how to set up different faces.  However, mmm-mode supports [highlighting submodes with a different background color](http://www.us.xemacs.org/Documentation/packages/html/mmm_3.html#SEC20).

Comment: I am using some version of git emacs that I compiled (I think I last updated a couple of months ago) and the git version of mmm-mode.

Comment: The apparent inability for mmm-mode to handle syntax coloring is a bit of a deal breaker for me. I've also found [doctest-mode](http://ed.loper.org/projects/doctestmode/), which also uses `mmm-mode` to do something like this, but with a focus on rendering and executing the doctests rather than the rst plain English.  But in either case, the doctest text color changes from my usual red to green (the same color as generic text). If I change the `mmm-mode-default-face`, then everything is red, and I loose syntax coloring (which is one of the main reasons I wanted to do this in the first place).

Comment: Oh, if you're using Emacs 24, mmm-mode has fairly serious known problems on that version.  That may be part of the issue.  [Some additional information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859773/getting-mmm-mode-to-work-in-emacs-24).  On the syntax coloring, if you disable mmm-mode's coloring entirely with `(setq mmm-submode-decoration-level 0)` you get the default syntax highlighting of the underlying mode.  I wonder if you could do something like set different rst-mode faces based on the file name in a file load hook.  Hm.

Comment: It's better to use just `"\"\"\""` for the front and back. The docstring delimiters do not have to be on their own line, and they do not have to be at the beginning or end. If some code doesn't follow what this specific regex expects, then a bunch of stuff will end up in the wrong mode, so getting it right is important.

Comment: One more suggestion:  By using sub-REs (`\\(\\)`) and removing the `:include` lines, only the part between the `"""` will be handled by rst.  This may e.g. allow some global formatting by python-mode's indenting and newline rules.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find another setup that check that the docstring is a statement itself. This avoid having rst in other heredoc.

https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/498

Answer (score 0):

As far as for edit-purposes, narrowing to docstring and activating rst-mode should be the way to go.

python-mode el provides py--docstring-p, which might be easily adapted for python.el

Than binding the whole thing to some idle-timer, would do the narrowing/switching.

Remains some expression which toggles-off rst-mode and widens.